# Dipole Moment of Normal Water vs Heavy Water

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, water, electronegativity, dipole, isotope

The question is in the title itself.

My guess: Higher for Normal water.

My Reasoning: Internet told me Deuterium is more electronegative than Protium. So,  there should be less difference between the electronegativity values of $\ce{D}$ and $\ce{O}$. Consequently, the dipole moment for $\ce{D2O}$ should be lower.

Is this a valid reasoning or should I take into account factors like lesser vibration amplitude of $\ce{D}$ than $\ce{H}$ that forms more stable bonds.

Comment: Dipole moment= Delta × distance
So the more the distance the more dipole moment. H2o have more dipole moment due to greater distance, so more vibration.

Answer (score 3):

There is no measurable difference.

HOH 1.8546 ± 0.0006 D

DOD 1.8558 ± 0.0021 D

[Dipole moment of water from Stark measurements of H2O, HDO, and D2O](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/59/5/10.1063/1.1680328) J. Chem. Phys. 59, 2254 (1973)

Comment: they are indeed very close to each other. But if I am to predict theoretically, how would I predict that? My reasoning seems to not match witg the data

Comment: @AmritanshSinghal you could think about bond length differences and bond angle differences, in addition to what you were already thinking about.  But I think it's completely unreasonable to decide which factor predominates when there is no measurable difference.